# how to create rectangular that had gradient left to right

Tags: html, css

I'm noob in css3 and I want create one div that had gradient from left to right.

I want this gradient start from white to black and I don't know how to create it? please guide me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and play with the available gradients by selecting different filters, rgb values. It is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

From here you can generate :

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients